# How does the JVM execute a servlet compared with a regular Java class?

Tags: java, servlets, jvm

How does the JVM execute a Servlet compared with a regular Java class?

Can it not be called similar to other java classes.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Servlet is instantiated by a container that implements the servlet specification. Implementing a servlet only has meaning in a Web application.

Is the container, like Tomcat, Wildfly and others that instantiates a Servlet object when it receives a request. The container instantiates `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` objects which are passed in a call to the `service` method which in turn passes them to the `doXXX` methods depending on the type of request, for example, GET or POST.

At the JVM level, servlets are just like other Java classes that could be instantiated but it would have no practical use since you need a request to be processed which is provided by the container.

Answer (score 6):

**Servlets are regular java classes and are executed by the JVM in exactly the same way as any other class.**

However, the environment or context in which the servlets execute is different.

A servlet is not invoked directly using a `main()` method like any other class.

The servlet class is invoked and executed by a web container (Like Apache Tomcat).

The container reads the configuration (like web.xml), identifies the servlet class, and uses java `classloader` system to load and run the servlets.